# Can someone tell me what this Chinese symbol means?

Tags: translation

[image]

I saw this as a tattoo and I wish to know what it means, please.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: [求](http://www.youdao.com/w/eng/%E6%B1%82/#keyfrom=dict2.index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character is 求, pronounced qiú.

Dictionary definition is:

n. request
vt. beg ; seek ; demand
misc. look for